# Matlab's way of getting p-values for correlation

Tags: matlab

I have a vector A of size N and I want to calculate a correlation coefficient and p-value for the correlation of A with some other vector B.

I used corrcoef in Matlab, something like this:

```
[R, P] = corrcoef(A, B)
```

And from what I understand, doing a t-test for this correlation `R(1,2)` to get a p-value equal to `P(1,2)` would mean calculating a test statistic 
`t = sqrt(N-2)*R./sqrt(1-R.^2)` 
and getting the p-value by

```
P = 1 - tcdf(t, N-2).
```

However, if I proceed in this way, the p-value that I get is not the same as the p-value Matlab calculated. Could someone explain why, or what am I missing in the calculation?
Thanks!

EDIT: Even if I do a two-sided test (`P = 2*(1-tcdf(abs(t), N-2))`), there's still a lot of differences in mine and Matlab's result.

Comment: The p-value expression is not correct. It can give p values beyond 1 sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check the relevant source codes of matlab and octave for p-value. The source code of octave is more clear.

Changing

```
P = 2*(1-tcdf(abs(t), N-2))
```

to

```
s = tcdf(t,N-2);
P = 2 * min(s,1-s);
```

does the trick. Then you get same p results as `corrcoef`.

Answer (score 2):

Think you may have the formula computed incorrectly for your t-stat. Looking at a basic stats [page](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch11-cor.html), we see that the formula for the t-stat is shown as below.

[image: T-stat]

It looks like you're doing a element-wise operation when one is not necessary.

Doing a test in matlab to prove this.

```
>> a=rand(14,1)

a =

    0.6110
    0.7788
    0.4235
    0.0908
    0.2665
    0.1537
    0.2810
    0.4401
    0.5271
    0.4574
    0.8754
    0.5181
    0.9436
    0.6377
>> b=rand(14,1)

b =

    0.0358
    0.1759
    0.7218
    0.4735
    0.1527
    0.3411
    0.6074
    0.1917
    0.7384
    0.2428
    0.9174
    0.2691
    0.7655
    0.1887
```

I first create two random vectors for a and b.

```
>> [R,p]=corrcoef(a,b)

R =

    1.0000    0.2428
    0.2428    1.0000


p =

    1.0000    0.4030
    0.4030    1.0000
```

R(1,2) is our rho in this case and my formula is computed exactly as above.

```
t=R(1,2)*sqrt((length(a)-2)/(1-R(1,2)^2))
t =

    0.8670


>> p=2*(1-tcdf(t,length(a)-2))

p =

    0.4030
```

You can see that the correlation coefficient does a 2 sided test.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! But I still don't get why doing an element-wise operation should be a problem... The result should still be the same, right?

Also. I am actually using this inside a function that is meant to work on both, scala anr vector data, that is why my formula is written element-wise. And it doesn't matter if I use it on a vector or scalar R - the p value I get in this described way (two sided test) still sometimes differs from Matlab's.  (Or if you want, when using it on a vector R, some of the elements of resulting p-value vector are different.)

Comment: Not sure what is different in your use case, I just redid my example item with your formula and the t stats match exactly with my formula which matches the matlab output for  2 sided test....  check your R?

Comment: Hm. The R vector seems fine, it's also calculated by Matlab directly.  But some of the results seem different, although mostly on 4th digit (only rarely more) - maybe that's just due to the rounding errors/different order of computation or something?  I contemplated this idea before posting the question, but it kind of seemed like too big of a difference still. Now I'm not sure anymore what to think. 

I guess it's not that important anyway right now, but I'm just really curious about it.

Comment: I made a test with different random vectors. `p=2*(1-tcdf(t,length(a)-2))` gives the same value as `corrcoef` sometimes but sometimes different. The subfunction to compute `p` in source code of `corrcoef` is much complex than the equation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by wsdzbm works. Here is the matlab code for an example of how to calculate the p-values the same way that matlab does in corrcoef if you only know the correlation coefficient matrix R and the number of samples N (compare p_check below for the manual calculation of the p-value compared with p from corrcoef):

```
load hospital
X = [hospital.Weight hospital.BloodPressure];
[R, p] = corrcoef(X)
N = size(X,1);
t = sqrt(N-2).*R./sqrt(1-R.^2);
s = tcdf(t,N-2);
p_check = 2 * min(s,1-s)
% R =
% 1.0000e+00   1.5579e-01   2.2269e-01
% 1.5579e-01   1.0000e+00   5.1184e-01
% 2.2269e-01   5.1184e-01   1.0000e+00
% p =
% 1.0000e+00   1.2168e-01   2.5953e-02
% 1.2168e-01   1.0000e+00   5.2460e-08
% 2.5953e-02   5.2460e-08   1.0000e+00
% p_check =
% 0            1.2168e-01   2.5953e-02
% 1.2168e-01            0   5.2460e-08
% 2.5953e-02   5.2460e-08            0
```